# Query with multiple where and same row

Tags: mysql, laravel-5.6

I want to show **data of student** that have this multiple characters (ex: handsome and smart), student must have both characters if student dont have both or only have one of characters then **DONT SHOW**.

i have tried using this code, but all data that contain the characters (handsome and smart) appear

Example :

```
$data = DB::table('student')->whereIn('characters', ['handsome','smart'])->get();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A working raw MySQL query for this requirement would look something like:

```
SELECT s1.*
FROM student s1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT id
    FROM student
    WHERE character IN ('handsome', 'smart')
    GROUP BY id
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT character) = 2
) s2
    ON s1.id = s2.id;
```

We can try writing the following Laravel code:

```
$characters = DB::table('student')
    ->select('id')
    ->whereIn('characters', ['handsome','smart'])
    ->groupBy('id')
    ->havingRaw('COUNT(DISTINCT character) = 2');

$matches = DB::table('student s1')
    ->joinSub($characters, 's2', function ($join) {
        $join->on('s1.id', '=', 's2.id');
    })
->get();
```

This answer assumes that the primary key column for the `student` table is called `id`.  If it be called something else, then update my code snippets to match that.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but the characters is dinamic not only 2, it can be 3,4,5,6,etc

Comment: Then just change the `whereIn()` to include all characteristics, and then assert the correct distinct count in `havingRaw()`.

Answer (score 0):

You may chain where constraints together as well as add or clauses to the query. The orWhere method accepts the same arguments as the where method:

```
$users = DB::table('student')
                    ->where('characters', 'handsome')
                    ->orWhere('characters', 'smart')
                    ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

put this where clause in your query, like below:

```
$student = \DB::table('student')
->whereExists(function ($query) {
$query->orWhere('characters', 'handsome')
->orWhere('characters', 'smart');
 })->get();
```